# How to join another table via altering view query as exposed filter

Tags: views

Hi I have created a view and exposed the view with node title. Searching is done on title and its working fine. But I have a requirement that when some one searches through title, the search text should also be matched to body field and if the content is found in any of the field it should display result. Like if the search text is not in title but found in body it should display the result as found.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter from the `Global` group as a `combined filter`. Then assure the View has both the `title` and `body` fields avaiable in the View (they can be `hidden` from the View if you want).

Then set the `combined filter` to use the `title` and `body` fields when a search is done.

Then your single exposed filter will show results from your query criteria from either of the fields.